# How to add the lambda on WAF accept origin

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-lambda, amazon-waf

I have lambda script which access the url.

In lambda.

```
url = "https://example.com"
req =  request.Request(url, data={})
res = request.urlopen(req)
```

As for, https://example.com/ (aws load balancer), there is a FW which accept only some ips defined by ipsets.

So, I need to add the rule to this FAW for passing the lambda access.

Is there any good way to to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want static IP for your lambda function for the outgoing internet traffic, you have to place your lambda in a VPC, in a **private subnet** and setup [NAT gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-nat-gateway.html). NATs have **static IPs** so your lambda will use that IP to access the internet.

Comment: Thank you for your help, through VPC is nice approach and I understood that NAT have static IP. However in this case , I set the original header in lambda request and use this header in WAF rule.